# How to store cherrypy.session() in a variable?

Tags: python, cherrypy

First, I store an email in my session:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def setter(self):
    email = "email@email.com"
    cherrypy.session["email"] = email
    return "Variable passed to session" // This works fine!
```

Second, I return the session data:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def getter(self):
    return cherrypy.session("email") // This works fine too!
```

But now, I would like to store this data in a variable and return it:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def getter(self):
    variable = cherrypy.session("email")
    return variable
```

When doing this, I get a 500 Internal: KeyError 'variable'

Comment: you have wrong indentions in examples and show full error message, There are other usefull information .

Comment: Yes, this is the message:                                                                         500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: File "/home/gr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/home/gr/.local/../encoding.py", line 220, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "app.py", line 73, in getter
    variable = cherrypy.session["email"]
  File "/home/gr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/__init__.py", line 254, in __getitem__
    return child[key]
  File "/home/gr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py", line 308, in __getitem__
    return self._data[key]
KeyError: 'email'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to turn sessions on in the config. It's disabled by default. Also, you use `cherrypy.session` as a dictionary, it's not a function you call.

Take this example code:

```
# rimoldi.py

import cherrypy

class TestApp:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def setter(self):
        email = "email@email.com"
        cherrypy.session["email"] = email
        return 'Variable stored in session object. Now check out the <a href="/getter">getter function</a>'

    @cherrypy.expose
    def getter(self):
        return "The email you set earlier, was " + cherrypy.session.get("email")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(TestApp(), "/", {
        "/": {
            "tools.sessions.on": True,
            }
        })
```

You run the above example with:

`python rimoldi.py`

CherryPy says:

```
[09/Jan/2017:16:34:32] ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080
[09/Jan/2017:16:34:32] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

Now point your browser at http://127.0.0.1:8080/setter, and you'll see:

**Variable stored in session object. Now check out the getter function**

Click the 'getter' link. The browser shows:

**The email you set earlier, was email@email.com**

Voila! This is how you use sessions in CherryPy. I hope this example helps you.